# Parametrize attributes of Django-models with multi-table inheritance in pytest-factoryboy

Tags: django, pytest, factory-boy, pytest-django

I am using `Django` and want to write a test using `pytest`, `pytest-django`, `pytest-factoryboy` and `pytest-lazyfixtures`.

I have Django-models that are using multi-table inheritance, like this:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    active = models.BooleanField()

class Editor(User):
    pass

class Admin(User):
   pass
```

I also created factories for all models and registered them, such as:

```py
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    created = ... # some datetime
    active = factory.Faker("pybool")

class EditorFactory(UserFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Editor

...
```

Now I want to test a function that can take any of `User`, `Editor` or `Admin` as an input and parametrize the test with all user types and variations of `active` and `created`, like this (unfortunately it doesn't work like that):

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("any_user", [lazy_fixture("user"), lazy_fixture("editor"), lazy_fixture("admin")])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("any_user__active", [True, False])
def test_some_func(any_user):
   ...  # test some stuff
```

However that fails with `In test_some_func: function uses no argument 'any_user__active'`.

Any idea how to best solve this?

I could of course do sth like this, but it's not as nice:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("any_user", [lazy_fixture("user"), lazy_fixture("editor"), lazy_fixture("admin")])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("active", [True, False])
def test_some_func(any_user, active):
   any_user.active = active
   # save any_user if necessary
   ...  # test some stuff
```

Any better suggestions?

Comment: What if you change: `@pytest.mark.parametrize("any_user__active", [True, False])` to `@pytest.mark.parametrize("user__active", [True, False])`?

Comment: Then I need to add `user` to the func def and it will only parametrize it for the `User`, not for the `Admin`. I could of course then also add `Admin`, but with all the attributes and types I need to parametrize that would be very verbose :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytest-factoryboy is not as expressive as I'd wish in cases like this. It would be nice to call `pytest_factoryboy.register` with an alternate name for model fixtures — but unfortunately, even though `register` takes a `_name` parameter intended for this purpose, `_name` is ignored, and `underscore(factory_class._meta.model.__name__)` is used instead.

Thankfully, we can trick this logic into using the model name we desire:

```
@register
class AnyUserFactory(UserFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = type('AnyUser', (User,), {})
```

Essentially, we create a new subclass of `User` with the name `AnyUser`. This will cause pytest-factoryboy to create the `any_user` model fixture, along with `any_user__active`, `any_user__created`, etc. Now, how do we parametrize `any_user` to use `UserFactory`, `EditorFactory`, and `AdminFactory`?

Thankfully again, model fixtures work by requesting the `model_name_factory` fixture with `request.getfixturevalue('model_name_factory')`, and not by directly referencing the `@register`'d factory class. The upshot is that we can simply override `any_user_factory` with whatever factory we wish!

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, params=[
    lazy_fixture('user_factory'),
    lazy_fixture('editor_factory'),
    lazy_fixture('admin_factory'),
])
def any_user_factory(request):
    return request.param
```

*NOTE: pytest seems to prune the graph of available fixtures based on the test method args, as well as any args requested by fixtures. When a fixture uses `request.getfixturevalue`, pytest may report being unable to find the requested fixture — even if it's clearly defined — because it was pruned. We pass `autouse=True` to our fixture, to force pytest into including it in the dependency graph.*

Now, we can parametrize `any_user__active` directly on our test, and `any_user` will be a `User`, `Editor`, and `Admin` with each value of `active`

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('any_user__active', [True, False])
def test_some_func(any_user):
    print(f'{type(any_user)=} {any_user.active=}')
```

Which outputs:

```
py.test test.py -sq

type(any_user)=<class 'test.User'> any_user.active=True
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.User'> any_user.active=False
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Editor'> any_user.active=True
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Editor'> any_user.active=False
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Admin'> any_user.active=True
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Admin'> any_user.active=False
.
6 passed in 0.04s
```

---

Also, if `@pytest.fixture` with `request.param` feels a bit verbose, I might suggest using [pytest-lambda](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-lambda/) (**disclaimer:** I am the author). Sometimes, `@pytest.mark.parametrize` can be limiting, or can require including extra arg names in the test method that go unused; in those cases, it can be convenient to declare new fixtures without writing the full fixture method.

```
from pytest_lambda import lambda_fixture

any_user_factory = lambda_fixture(autouse=True, params=[
    lazy_fixture('user_factory'),
    lazy_fixture('editor_factory'),
    lazy_fixture('admin_factory'),
])

@pytest.mark.parametrize('any_user__active', [True, False])
def test_some_func(any_user):
    print(f'{type(any_user)=} {any_user.active=}')
```

---

If including `autouse=True` on `any_user_factory` is bothersome, because it causes all other tests to be parametrized, we have to find some other way to include `any_user_factory` in the pytest dependency graph.

Unfortunately, the first approach I'd try caused errors. I tried to override the `any_user` fixture, requesting both the original `any_user` fixture, and our overridden `any_user_factory`, like this

```
@pytest.fixture
def any_user(any_user, any_user_factory):
    return any_user
```

Alas, pytest didn't like that

```
___________________________ ERROR collecting test.py ___________________________
In test_some_func: function uses no argument 'any_user__active'
```

Fortunately, pytest-lambda provides a decorator to wrap a fixture function, so the arguments of both the decorated method and the wrapped fixture are preserved. This allows us to explicitly add `any_user_factory` to the dependency graph

```
from pytest_lambda import wrap_fixture

@pytest.fixture(params=[  # NOTE: no autouse
    lazy_fixture('user_factory'),
    lazy_fixture('editor_factory'),
    lazy_fixture('admin_factory'),
])
def any_user_factory(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
@wrap_fixture(any_user)
def any_user(any_user_factory, wrapped):
    return wrapped()  # calls the original any_user() fixture method
```

*NOTE: `@wrap_fixture(any_user)` directly references the `any_user` fixture method defined by pytest_factoryboy when calling @register. It'll appear as an unresolved reference in most static code checkers / IDEs; but as long as it appears after `class AnyUserFactory` and in the same module, it will work.*

Now, only tests which request `any_user` will hit `any_user_factory` and receive its parametrization.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('any_user__active', [True, False])
def test_some_func( any_user):
    print(f'{type(any_user)=} {any_user.active=}')

def test_some_other_func():
    print('some_other_func')
```

Output:

```
py.test test.py -sq

type(any_user)=<class 'test.User'> any_user.active=True
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.User'> any_user.active=False
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Editor'> any_user.active=True
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Editor'> any_user.active=False
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Admin'> any_user.active=True
.type(any_user)=<class 'test.Admin'> any_user.active=False
.some_other_func
.
7 passed in 0.06 seconds
```

Comment: Cool stuff! I am still having a few issues here, e.g., `autouse=True` causes it to run all tests (in the `any_user_factory`-scope) 3x, even if they don't use `any_user`. Alternatively I could add `any_user_factory` to the test-funcs where I use `any_post`, but that's also not super nice. I am still experimenting with other options, trying to attach the factory-fixture to the `any_post` model-fixture somehow.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's annoying. Well, one way to handle that is to put all tests using `any_user` into their own class/module, and only override `any_user_factory` there, so its `autouse=True` doesn't impact other tests. But that's dirty, and just one more thing to have to remember. A more effective solution would be somehow adding `any_user_factory` as an explicit argument to the `any_user` fixture. I'll edit my answer with an example of that. I've run into situations like this before, and included a util to address it in pytest-lambda.

Answer (score 0):

> However that fails with In test_some_func: function uses no argument
>   'any_user__active'.

This is because you haven't passed this `any_user__active` as the argument on the test function.
so change your test file to

```
def test_some_func(any_user__active, any_user):
```

An example will be like as below

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("days, expected", [
        (-1, 0),
        (1, 1),
        (0, 0),
        (365, 365)
    ])
def test_subscription_to_for_user(days, expected):
```

Comment: The `__attribute` notation is part of [pytest-factoryboy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/) and is available for registered factories. Of course, `any_user` is not a registered factory and that's why it fails. However, your suggestion doesn't really do what I am trying to do :-) Thanks anyways!